# Git ignore explicitly a file without ignoring similar files

Tags: git

I have a `TypeScript/Angular5` project, in which I defined a `.gitignore` file in the `src/environment` directory. The content is a single line: `/environment.ts`. Which ignores the `environment.ts` file, but also ignore the `environment.sample.ts` file.

Why? It was supposed to ignore the file I mentioned in the ignore file, but it still ignores another one with similar name. Interestingly, it does not ignore the file named `environment.prod.ts`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check `.gitignore` in `src/.gitignore` or the `.gitignore` directive in the root working directory; its possible there could be a conflict

Comment: Hmm, the IDE added two rows to my `.gitignore` file in the root, ignore the sample file. Thanks for reminding me.